# how to save grid search results in variable in python

Tags: python

I am applying SARIMA on a train dataset, where I am searching order of SARIMA through grid search, where I get lowest AIC score. I want to save all the results in list with ARIMA order, seasonal order and AIC score, then I want to pick parameters with lowest AIC score.

```
p = d = q = range(0, 2)
pdq = list(itertools.product(p, d, q))
seasonal_pdq = [(x[0], x[1], x[2], 12) for x in list(itertools.product(p, d, q))]

for param in pdq:
    for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
        try:
            mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(train,
                                        order=param,
                                        seasonal_order=param_seasonal,
                                        enforce_stationarity=False,
                                        enforce_invertibility=False)
            results = mod.fit()

            print('ARIMA{}x{}12 - AIC:{}'.format(param, param_seasonal, results.aic))
        except:
            continue
```

I want to store results in `a` e.g. `a[1] = [(0,1,1),(1,1,1,12),234,56]`

And then find lowest AIC score in `a` and apply it in following model fit

```
  mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(train,
                            order=(0, 1, 1),
                            seasonal_order=(1, 1, 1, 12),
                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                            enforce_invertibility=False)
  results = mod.fit()
```

Comment: Why not just loop across `a` after you store your results in it and return the index with the lowest AIC value and use its parameters in the SARIMA model? It seems trivial and you have a high score, so maybe I'm missing something.